# Dreams come true or they are fulfilled. What about 'hopes'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, collocation

Let's say things went the way we had hoped they would. Would it be appropriate, then, to say, *'our hopes were fulfilled'* or is there a more acceptable or better expression? Apparently, *'things went the way we had hoped...'* sounds good enough but I am wondering if there are other patterns or collocations for 'hopes'.

Comment: Hopes are invariably _dashed_.

Comment: @BrianHooper  I prefer to *hyphenate* hopes :-)

Comment: @Brian: But we're constantly being reminded *wishes aren't horses* (since if they were, beggars would ride), and adivsed to be *careful what we wish for* (in case it comes true in a way we're not expecting). On the other hand, *dreams* are often *realised* - so ***dream on!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopes *come true* also. Wishes, dreams, hopes, predictions; they can all *come true*. Although, it is less commonly used for hopes. Hopes can be *fulfilled* also.

> **to come true:** to be verified by the course of events; to be realized in actual experience; to be fulfilled. Cf. *to hold true* at hold v. 23c. 
> <sub>*a (also one's) dream come true*: see dream *n.<sup>2</sup>* and *adj.* Phrases 2.</sub> 
> *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/206884?redirectedFrom=come%20true#eid17363648)*

The last three examples from *OED*:

> 1876      W. Morris tr. Virgil *Æneids* viii. 211     While yet my fear is unfulfilled and **hope** may yet come true. 
> 1963      N. Coward *Diary* 17 Mar. (2000) 530     What I **predicted**..has come true. 
> 2011      *Vanity Fair* May 152/2     My lifelong **dream** came true. 
> <sub>emphasis mine</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Our hopes are **REALISED** (hopefully!).

Does that suit you?

Answer (score 0):

A dream coming true, assuming a literal dream as opposed to using "dream" as a synonym for a wild hope, means that some scenario you recall from a dream actually happened.

Fulfulling a hope, on the other hand, means an event or condition you wish for was granted (sort of like "granting a wish").

So, perhaps you could use  "...our desires were met,"  or "the results were what we'd hoped for."